# chat.megagroup not showing all the groups in Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using `chat.megagroup==true`
it is not showing all the channels (in `m==1`),
and it's also have issues like sometimes group A and group B is shown, sometimes either A or B is shown, sometimes group C is shown, 
don't know why it's happening without even changing anything in the code.

The script is overall working fine but the only issue is that I'm not having the groups sometimes, that are needed to use.

```
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0))

chats.extend(result.chats)
dialogs = client.get_dialogs()

m = input("1: For only permitted groups \n2: For all groups\n")
if m=='1':
    for chat in chats:
        try:
            if chat.megagroup == True:
                groups.append(chat)
        except:
            continue
elif m=='2':
    for i in dialogs:
        try:
            i.entity.status
        except:
            groups.append(i)
            continue
```

In `m==2`, all the groups are shown.
Can you please guide what I'm doing wrong or it's something else?

Comment: *I'm trying to fetch members and sending them invites for other groups*. Do remember this is spam and your account and groups will likely be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, sorry once again :s

Comment: Anyone, please?